# Is there a clever(er) way to construct a finite field with nine elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I was given a hint to consider $\mathbb{F}_9=\mathbb{F}_3[\beta]=\{a+b\beta:a,b\in\mathbb{F}_3\},$ where $\mathbb{F}_3=\{0,1,2\}$ is the set of integers modulo $3$. The distributive law says for $a+b\beta,a'+b'\beta\in\mathbb{F}_9$, $(a+b\beta)(a'+b'\beta)=aa'+(ba'+ab')\beta+(bb')\beta^2\in \mathbb{F}_9$. I know that $aa',ba'+ab',bb'\in\{0,1,2\}$ since $\mathbb{F}_3$ is a field. So $(aa',ba'+ab',bb')\in\{0,1,2\}^3$. This gives 27 elements, and I want to find $\beta$ so that there are exactly 9 distinct elements. I know I can do this by checking if each pair of the elements is equal, but I don't know if I will finish the $\sum_{k=1}^{26} k$ comparisons before my homework set is due - I certainly hope this is not the intended approach.

Is there an insight I'm missing here? Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: You need $\beta^2$ to be an element of the field $\Bbb{F}_9$. Can you show that if you postulate $\beta^2=-1$ everything will work out nicely? If you have covered basic theory of field extensions you should be able to see that if you can show the polynomial $x^2+1$ to be irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_3$ you are done. Alternatively you can construct this field as $\Bbb{Z}[i]/\langle 3\rangle$, but proving the absence of zero divisors takes a bit of work if you follow that route.

Comment: **HINT**: $\beta^2$ can be mapped wherever you want.

Comment: @Jsevillamol That's not true. If you map $\beta$ to, say, $0$, you won't get a field.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I have not seen irreducible polynomials yet. I will look into those. Taking your hint, I have 14 elements: $\{0,-1,-2,\beta,\beta+1,\beta+2,2\beta,2\beta+1,2\beta+2,1,\beta-1,2\beta-1,2,1\}$. Much less to check than with 27 elements! What is the idea behind guessing $\beta^2=-1$? Is there a systematic method to come up with such a guess?

Comment: Remember that you are working modulo $3$, so $-1=2$. The systematic method is to find an irreducible polynomial of a suitable degree. For quadratic extensions that is easy. In general it is to prove that they exist than to produce one.

Answer (score 2):

This is just Jyrki's comment, I think some people gain confidence from the matrix approach, which seems familiar, comfortable.

Take $a,b$ in your field, then make the 2 by 2 matrix $$ aI + b B,  $$ where
$$
B =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

What is $B^2?$ What is $$ (aI + b B)(cI + dB)?  $$
If at least one of $a,b$ is nonzero in the field, and at least one of $c,d$ is nonzero in the field, is it possible for the product $ (aI + b B)(cI + dB)  $ to be the zero matrix?

The multiplicative identity is now  $I.$ For a nonzero matrix here, what is the multiplicative inverse of  $aI + bB?$

Answer (score 2):

Take any irreducible quadratic polynomial in $\mathbf F_3[x]$, for instance $x^2+1$. Let $\beta$ the congruence class of $x$ in $\;\mathbf F_3[x]/(x^2+1)$, which is a field with $9$ elements:
$$\{0,\pm 1,\pm\beta,\pm 1\pm\beta\}.$$